# Display the top 2 highest difference car records

Tags: python

How to display the top 2 rows of highest difference from a text file in python
For example here is a text file:

```py
Mazda 64333 53333
Merce 74321 54322
BMW   52211 31432
```

The expected output would be

```py
Merce 74321 54322
BMW   52211 31432
```

I tried multiple codes but only managed to display the actual difference and not the whole row.

Comment: post the "codes" you tried

Comment: Are there other ways to do it without importing so that I understand it better, I don't consider my self an expert nor a beginner. The only import ik are import math, mathplot, random

Comment: i have posted an answer that does not require external imports

Comment: ill edit with an explanation

Comment: edited w/ an in-depth explanation, I hope that helps :)

Comment: thank you so much for your time :))

Comment: no problemo, if you liked the answer you can always click the checkmark so other users can see it worked in the future. Thanks for asking and happy coding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would this work for you?

```
from operator import itemgetter

with open("x.txt", "r+") as data:
    data = [i.split() for i in data.readlines()]
    top = sorted([[row[0], int(row[1])-int(row[2])]for row in data],key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print(top)
print(top[:2])
```

```
[['BMW', 20779], ['Merce', 19999], ['Mazda', 11000]]
[['BMW', 20779], ['Merce', 19999]]
```

So, at a glance, this might seem slightly complicated but it's really not!

let's break down each step of the following program

```
from operator import itemgetter

with open("x.txt", "r+") as data:
    data = [i.split() for i in data.readlines()]
    top = sorted([[row[0], int(row[1])-int(row[2])]for row in data],key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

now let's first note that `operator` is a built-in package, it's not an external import such as libraries like requests, and `itemgetter` is a pretty straightforward function.

`with open("x.txt", "r+") as data` should be pretty straight forward as well... all this does is open a text file with reading permissions and store that object in `data`.

we then use our first list comprehension which might look new to you...

```
data = [i.split() for i in data.readlines()]
```

all this is doing is going through each line for example `car 123 122` and splitting it by spaces into a list like so `["car", "123", "122"]`.

Now if you look closely at the product of that, there's something wrong. The last 2 elements (which need to be integers to find the difference) are strings! hence, why we are going to have to use the next list comprehension to change that.

```
top = sorted([[row[0], int(row[1])-int(row[2])]for row in data],key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

This is a bit more complicated... but all it's really doing is sorting a simple list comprehension.

It goes through each value in `data` and gets the differences! Let's see how it does that.

As you know, our data looks something like `[["car", "123", "122"], ["car1", "1234", "1223"]]` right now. So, we would be able to access the integer values of `["car", "123", "122"]` with `[1]` and `[2]`, with this knowledge we can loop through the data, and get the difference of those when they are casted to integers. E.g `int(row[1])-int(row[2])` of `["car", "123", "122"]` would return `1` (the difference).

With this knowledge, we can create a new list with the comprehension that contains: the car's name `row[0]` and the difference `int(row[1])-int(row[2])` represented by `[row[0], int(row[1])-int(row[2])]` in the list comp. while using row as each iterable in data we can easily form this! Heres that list comprehension by itself:

```
[[row[0], int(row[1])-int(row[2])] for row in data]
```

Finally, we have arrived at the last piece of this little program... the `sorted` function! `sorted()` will return a sorted list based on the key you give it (and you can use `reverse=True` to have the greatest values first). it's really not that hard to understand when it's abbreviated as follows:

```
sorted([the list comprehension],key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

So while you might know that yes, it's sorting that list comprehension we made and listing the biggest values first, you might not know **how** its sorting this! To know how it's being sorted we need to look at the `key`.

`itemgetter()` is a function of the operator class. All you really need to know about it is that it's getting the 1st index of the lists given and therefore sorting by that. If you can recall each element of our data looks like `["car", difference]` (`difference` is just a placeholder for what actually is the integer difference). Since we want the greatest differences then it makes sense to sort by them right?

using `itemgetter(1)` it will sort by the 1st index; *the difference*! and that pretty much sums it up :)

we store all of that to the variable `top` and then print the first two elements with `print(top[:2])`

I hope this helped!

Answer (score -1):

Create a `dict` that contains the distances of each row with the car brand as key.
Then you can sort the `dict.items()` using the `values` and return the top 2